# Rainbow gradient on text in CSS

Tags: css

What would be the best way to achieve this design in CSS?

[image]

and this:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Read http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp It should cover your question.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here is how you can create basic rainbow linear gradient (without integration with text yet):

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Or alternatively, you can use one of the gradient generators (I prefer [this one](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)).

And here is the text integration:

```css
#grad1 {
    background: red;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="grad1">Fake Text</h1>
```

Main parts here are `background-clip` and `text-fill-color` properties, but be ready, that not all browsers will support it. For more info about browser compatibility check sections with the same names near the bottoms of these pages:

[background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

[text-fill-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color)

**P.S.**
Drawing a line is pretty simple, you just need to use a gradient and define some styles to make this block the right form, for example:

```css
#grad1 {
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

.line {
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1" class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 14):

If you need that same gradient for the text use something like this.

```css
    h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h1>100% Unicorn</h1>
```

But text-fill-color isn´t supported in Internet Explorer. 
So perhaps its better to use transparent png or svg in foreground.

Answer (score 5):

**In CSS file:**

```
.rainbow {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );

background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );

color:transparent;

border: 2px dotted white;

-webkit-background-clip: text;

background-clip: text;

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use this [gradient generator](http://angrytools.com/gradient/). Add colours at different points and use the rotate option.

It will generate the CSS for you.

Answer (score 2):

**precise HSL values**

```css
.rainbow{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 191, 0), rgb(128, 255, 0), rgb(0, 255, 64), rgb(0, 255, 255), rgb(0, 64, 255), rgb(128, 0, 255), rgb(255, 0, 191), rgb(255, 0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the default value of orange and yellow is not easily readable on a white background so here's the improved version:

[image]

CSS:

```css
 background-image: linear-gradient(to left, violet, indigo, blue, green, #d2d20f, #eb9c0b, red);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

React JSX:

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundImage:
      "linear-gradient(to left, violet, indigo, blue, green, #d2d20f, #eb9c0b, red)",
    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
    WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent",
  }}
>
  That's all, folks!
</div>;
```