# How to have one word with unique coloring while others are normal?

Tags: javascript, text, colors, theme-ui

[Image of the wanted output, the "Blockchain" text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkX6O.png)

I tried this:

```
<Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Innovate your idea with <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Blockchain</Text></Text>
```

Which generates this
[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUFjM.png):

There are two problems, first one I couldn't find a way to have multicolored text in a sentence. Second when i tried to have a uniquely colored word in a sentence it will go to a new line and not stay on the same line.

Comment: I'm not sure what a `Text` element is, maybe a paragraph? If you use a `span` it will go inline. Here's an example of rainbow text with css, you can use it as inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557461/rainbow-gradient-on-text-in-css

Comment: @Tom thank you Tom your suggestion worked fantastically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Tom for the the help

In the CSS

```
 #bc {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #5476E9,cyan);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #5476E9,cyan);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #5476E9,cyan);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #5476E9,cyan);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

In the code:

```
   Innovate your idea with <span id="bc">Blockchain</span>
```

Reference:
[Rainbow gradient on text in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557461/rainbow-gradient-on-text-in-css)